# Person or Group passed in Site Column - Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-column

Creating a multi tiered SharePoint site for managing certifications and other different types of records that relate to a person. I have created a roster that has all the personal information for the individual and has an "Person or Group" Column that assigns the account to that persons record. My intention is to use the assigned account column to generate views and reports based on who is logged in at the time. I have set up a Site Column to pass the values to the different Lists and Libraries but I am having some difficulty passing the "Person or Group" Value that is assigned as metadata to a list item. When I create the Site Column it is not a value that can be selected and after creation it is not included on the receiving lists or libraries. Aside from setting up a workflow or custom code to make it happen, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

No, to my best of knowledge, there is no other way than workflow or custom code. Searching for "SharePoint 2013 filter by user" gives search results on third party tools and custom code which is usually a good indication of lack of functionality in SharePoint.

Comment: Is the question really about redirecting? I might be reading it wrong, but to me it feels like it is about Person / Group fields? :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren Not outspoken, no. Maybe I'm confusing the asker of what can't be done and what haven't been asked. *Editing*